# AWK : Ensure only one blank line after the output block

Tags: awk

The following awk code outputs what is required except that it outputs two blank lines after each block of data. Only one blank line needs to be inserted. (Without the last {"print "\n"} statement, no blank lines are output. With the statement, there are two blank lines. I need only one blank line.)

```
/Reco/ {for(i=0; i<=2; i++) {getline; print} {print "\n"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment below that you actually want `the line that matches /Reco/ and 2 subsequent lines and a blank line (to be inserted after that)` here's how to do that based on idiom "g" below:

```
awk '/Reco/{c=3} c&&c--{print; if(!c)print ""}' file
```

wrt an explanation - just remember that awk provides this functionality for you:

```
WHILE read line from file
DO
    execute the users script (/Reco/{c=3} c&&c--{print; if(!c)print ""})
DONE
```

and that the body of an awk script is made up of:

```
<condition> { <action> }
```

statements with the default condition being TRUE and the default action being to print the current record/line.

The posted awk script above does the following:

```
/Reco/ {         # IF the pattern "Reco" is present on the current line THEN
    c=3          #     Set the count of the number of lines to print to 3
}                # ENDIF
c&&c-- {         # IF c is non-zero THEN decrement c and THEN
    print;       #     print the current line
    if(!c)       #     IF c is now zero (i.e. this is the 3rd line) THEN
        print "" #         print a blank line
                 #     ENDIF
}                # ENDIF
```

so the whole execution of parsing the input file is:

```
WHILE read line from file
DO
    /Reco/ {         # IF the pattern "Reco" is present on the current line THEN
        c=3          #     Set the count of the number of lines to print to 3
    }                # ENDIF
    c&&c-- {         # IF c is non-zero THEN decrement c and THEN
        print;       #     print the current line
        if(!c)       #     IF c is now zero (i.e. this is the 3rd line) THEN
            print "" #         print a blank line
                     #     ENDIF
    }                # ENDIF
DONE
```

Maybe it'd be a little clearer if the script was written as something like:

```
awk '/Reco/{c=3} c{c--; print; if(c == 0)print ""}' file
```

---

You got the answer you were looking for but here's how to really print the N lines after some pattern in awk:

```
c&&c--;/pattern/{c=N}
```

which in your case would be:

```
c&&c--;/Reco/{c=3}
```

and if you want to add that extra newline then it becomes:

```
c&&c--{print; if(!c)print ""} /Reco/{c=3}
```

If you're considering using `getline` make sure you read http://awk.info/?tip/getline first and understand all of the caveats so you know what you're getting yourself into.

P.S. The following idioms describe how to select a range of records given
a specific pattern to match:

a) Print all records from some pattern:

```
awk '/pattern/{f=1}f' file
```

b) Print all records after some pattern:

```
awk 'f;/pattern/{f=1}' file
```

c) Print the Nth record after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=N}' file
```

d) Print every record except the Nth record after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&!--c{next}/pattern/{c=N}1' file
```

e) Print the N records after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&c--;/pattern/{c=N}' file
```

f) Print every record except the N records after some pattern:

```
awk 'c&&c--{next}/pattern/{c=N}1' file
```

g) Print the N records from some pattern:

```
awk '/pattern/{c=N}c&&c--' file
```

I changed the variable name from "f" for "found" to "c" for "count" where
appropriate as that's more expressive of what the variable actually IS.

Comment: Thanks. Will look up the link.

Comment: You're welcome. I just updated my answer to add some other common awk idioms for finding a pattern and printing after it. Using `getline` is rarely the best approach to solving a problem with awk.

Comment: I want the line that matches /Reco/ and 2 subsequent lines and a blank line (to be inserted after that).
The code
 c&&c--;/Reco/{c=3};
prints 3 lines but after the line containing /Reco/
Also, please help with inserting a blank line after the 3 lines starting with the line with "Reco" in it.

Comment: That'd be a tweak to idiom "g" to add printing the blank line. I just updated my answer to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Ed. It works exactly as it should. However, I am clueless as to how the code works. Any pointers to resources that will help me break down the code and understand it better? (That will also help me understand the other variants that you have listed.)

Comment: I just added some comments and an explanation. Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2):

@Kevin's post provides the specific answer (use `print ""` or, as suggested by @BMW, `printf ORS`), but here's some **background**:

In `awk`,

```
print
```

is the same as:

```
print $0
```

i.e., it prints the current input line *followed by the output record separator* - which defaults to `\n` and is stored in the special `ORS` variable.

You can pass arguments to `print` to print something other than (or in addition to) `$0`, but the record separator is invariably appended.

Note that if you pass *multiple arguments separated with* `,` to `print`, they will be output separated by the *output field separator* - which defaults to a space and is stored in the special variable `OFS`.

By contrast, the - more flexible - **`printf`** function takes a *format string* (as in its C counterpart) and as many arguments as are needed to instantiate the placeholders (fields) in the format string.
An output record separator is NOT appended to the result.

For instance, the `printf` equivalent of what `print` without arguments does is:

```
printf "%s\n", $0  # assumes that \n is the output record separator
```

Or, more generally:

```
printf "%s%s", $0, ORS
```

Note that, as the names suggest, the *output* field/record separators (`OFS`/`ORS`) have *input* counterparts (`FS`/`RS`) - their respective default values are identical (single space / `\n` - though on parsing *input* multiple adjacent spaces are treated as a single field separator).

Comment: @user1955215: You're welcome; turns out my explanation mistakenly referenced the _input_ separators (FS/RS) rather than the _output_ separators (OFS/ORS); please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`print` already includes the newline. Just use `print ""`.

Comment: Modified the code to 
/Reco/ {for(i=0; i<=2; i++) {getline; print} {print}}
It prints the last line twice instead of a blank line

Comment: Or `printf RS`. OP need understand the difference of `printf RS` and `print RS`

Comment: @user1955215 `print` prints the current line. Use `print ""` (empty quotes), like I said.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Sorry, I had missed out on the "" earlier.  BMW, Will check the different print statements.